# remove one or more <tr> tag xpath php

Tags: php, html, xpath

question: In my code I want remove header tr html tag (witch attribute is`<tr class='background1'>` )

urL http://www.rayansaba.com/index.php?ukey=pricelist

In following code is if condition to avoid headers but I don't no way cant remove.

```
$table_rows = $xpath->query("//div[@class='cpt_maincontent']/center/table/tr"); // target the row (the browser rendered <tbody>, but actually it really doesnt have one)

if($table_rows->length <= 0) { // exit if not found
    echo 'no table rows found';
    exit;
}
 $i = 0;
 $trlength = count($table_rows);

foreach($table_rows as $tr){
$row = $tr->childNodes;
   if($row->item(0)->tagName!='<tr class="background1"></tr>') { // avoid headers
        $data[] = array(
            'Name' => trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'Price' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),





        );

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can just add it inside the xpath query excluding those rows with background, then extract the values and push the node values accordingly. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.rayansaba.com/index.php?ukey=pricelist');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$table_rows = $xpath->query("//div[@class='cpt_maincontent']/center/table/tr[not(@class)]");
$data = array();
foreach($table_rows as $tr) {
    if($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->length > 2) {
        $name = trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $price = trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->nodeValue);
        $data[] = array('Name' => $name, 'Price' => $price);
    }

}
echo '<pre>', print_r($data, 1), '</pre>';
```

Comment: 2 question -- why use [not(@class)] //// and what is length and why length > 2 ? @Ghost

Comment: I have one problem , In top site The table have different section(witch color bar is blue) // see first section names is - Laptops / Notebooks - and second is ASUS  and after is  ACER ,... Now I want only get name and price Laptops / Notebooks section.. all sections are in one table. For this reason and aren't in different table , I cant extract specific section. How can? @Ghost